# What's the difference between a Proof System and a Theory?

Tags: logic, formal-proofs

I found this question [Is the axiom of induction required for proving the first Gödel's incompleteness theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3710673/is-the-axiom-of-induction-required-for-proving-the-first-g%c3%b6dels-incompleteness)

I am apparently under the (wrong) impression that a theory and a proof system are synonyms. I'm pointing this out because from the accepted answer:

> Note that the term "(in)complete" is annoyingly overloaded: (in)completeness of a theory is a very different thing from (in)completeness of a proof system.

I am also currently reading a [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470905883) at leisure hoping to understand the basics well enough.

In the first few pages, the book defines:

> A logical system consists of the following:
>
> - An alphabet
> - A grammar
> - Propositional forms that require no proof
> - Rules that determine truth
> - Rules that are used to write proofs.

I'm not quite sure whether this definition is akin to a *theory* or a *proof system*. From where I currently stand, where the lines are drawn is very unclear. Maybe this definition describes both a theory and a proof system? Any help clearing this up would be very appreciated.

*This book was recommended by one of my professors as it does cover *some* model theory which is what I'm hoping to learn. Well, in honesty my goal is to have a **very clear idea** of what people are talking about when discussing the "good" stuff about $ZFC$, $Q$, $PA$, etc. I decided to look into how the book introduces the fundamentals, mostly because I've already covered first-order logic in a previous CS unit about formal languages.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the difference between a Proof System and a Theory?

A [proof system](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Proof_System) is the "logical machinery" made of logical axioms and rules of inference, like [propositional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) and [predicate calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic).

A formal mathematical theory is based on axioms; see e.g. the first-order version of [Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) and [Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) built using first-order logical language and using the "calculus" to prove theorems.

See Leary, page 68:

> The term *theory* refers to a collection of propositions all surrounding a particular subject. Since different theories have different notation (think about how algebraic notation differs from geometric notation), alphabets change depending on the subject matter.

This means that we start with the basic alphabet of first-order logic [see Def.2.1.2] made of variables, logical connectives and quantifiers, and develop the theory of sets using (in addition to *equality*) a single "theory symbol": the binary relation symbol $\in$, where $(x \in y)$ reads:

> "$x$ is an *element of* $y$".

---

Using examples from [Leary's book](https://books.google.it/books?id=pzGPCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA23), we have propositional axioms: $⊢ p→(q→p)$ [axiom FL1, page 24] and rules of inference: *Modus Ponens* [1.2.10], as well as rules regarding the quantifiers: $\forall x p(x) \to p(a)$ [Universal Instantiation, page 87].

In the development of set theory we will use them to prove mathematical theorems starting from mathematical axioms and using logical axioms and rules.

---

---

The definitions above are consistent with the terms used in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3710673/is-the-axiom-of-induction-required-for-proving-the-first-g%c3%b6dels-incompleteness) you have linked about [Gödel Incompleteness Theorem](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/).

In that case, the post is about the formal mathematical *theory* $\mathsf Q$, the so-called [Robinson arithemtic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic): a first-order mathematical theory that is a fragment (sub-system) of first-order Peano arithmetic ($\mathsf {PA}$).

Comment: So, when you say "calculus", what are you referring to if not a proof system that employs the axioms of, say, ZFC?

Comment: @Threnody - not exactly; the propositional calculus is defined with logical axioms: $\vdash p \to (q \to p)$ [axiom FL1, page 24] and rules of inference [e.g. *Modus Ponens*].

Comment: I think we're getting confused over semantics, perhaps I could've worded it better. A calculus like "propositional calculus" is just another name for "a specific proof system for propositional logic". Am I lost? I'm sorry if I'm being too pedantic

Comment: @Threnody - yes; we have the language of propositional logic: propositional variables + connectives and we have the *calculus* (aka: proof system) made of propositional axioms and propositional rules of inference. We have many equivalent [propositional proof systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hilbert_systems)

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much :)

Comment: @Threnody - you are welcome :-)